# Function to handle property with dot

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to handle this post request, i have a page that posts the data like

> https://localhost:80/Test/ValidateZeroBounce?ClientInfo.Email=test@test.comm

I have created a function in the controller which handle the data in a class object, but it remains always null

```
public ActionResult ValidateZeroBounce(ClientInfo Model)
        {
}

 public class ClientInfo
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string EmailJoint { get; set; }
    }
```

how I can handle that value ?

Comment: Why don't you put the parameters in the body? You say its a POST. So putting it in the body seems pretty normal. Add a [FromUri] before the ClientInfo Argument and then just call the Uri Parameter as they are named in that class. So only "Email" or "EmailJoint".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to startup

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
});
```

then you can use this syntax

```
https://localhost/Test/ValidateZeroBounce?Email=test@test.comm
```

or you can try this, but in this case it doesn't make much sense

```
https://localhost/Test/ValidateZeroBounce?model.Email=test@test.comm
```

or if you use an old version net , it is easier to do this way

```
public ActionResult ValidateZeroBounce(string email, string emailJoint)
{
var model= new ClientInfo {Email=email, EmailJoint=emailJoint};
....
}
```